# Inno Setup check if a machine is joined to a Domain

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way of checking whether the machine you are installing on is joined to a Domain or in a Workgroup?

I found this article about how to do this in Delphi, but I am unable to get this working within Inno Setup. Can anyone assist with this? Is this even possible?

http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/computer-in-a-domain.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would translate (and shorten) it this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  NERR_BASE = 2100;
  NERR_SetupNotJoined = NERR_BASE + 592;

type
  NET_API_STATUS = DWORD;

function NetRenameMachineInDomain(lpServer: WideString;
  lpNewMachineName: WideString; lpAccount: WideString;
  lpPassword: WideString; fRenameOptions: DWORD): NET_API_STATUS;
  external 'NetRenameMachineInDomain@netapi32.dll stdcall';

function IsInDomain: Boolean;
begin 
  Result := NetRenameMachineInDomain('', '', '', '', 0) <> NERR_SetupNotJoined;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  if IsInDomain then
    MsgBox('Is in domain.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox('Is not in domain.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, it gives an "Unknown type 'WideString'" compiler error.

Comment: That's because you are using ANSI version of Inno Setup. This function cannot be (correctly) imported in ANSI version since it uses parameters of type `LPCWSTR`. You can use this function only in Unicode Inno Setup. When you don't explicitly specify I'm assuming Unicode version because it's 2014 :-)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't actually realise there were two different versions. I will download and install the Unicode version. Hopefully, I won't have to change much of my code and scripting.

Comment: I have now switched over to the Unicode version. Surprisingly the only changes I had to make were a few PChar to PAnsiChar types. Things are rarely that straightforward! I can now confirm this is working perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, the code from that article (which I've shortened here) is badly designed. Better make an `IsNotInDomain` function checking if the value returned by the `NetRenameMachineInDomain` function call equals to `NERR_SetupNotJoined`. That's because the function may fail for many reasons (like e.g. access denied) which should not result in assumption that the machine is in domain. In such case you don't know that information.